# What are advantages of capturing the Infomessages of SQL connections?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently reviewing/redoing code of a collegue of mine and stumbled upon a construct I've never seen done before:

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.....");
con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
con.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(myInfoMessage);
```

With:

```
void myInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (SqlError err in e.Errors) 
    {
        errors += err.LineNumber.ToString() + ": " + err.Message + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Now as far as I understand it all but really severe errors can be captured this way (17+ class errors not as they will stay exceptions). Now what I get is that in some cases you could not want to have an exception thrown and catched, but instead want it as an info message (or a flag set). In this case I see this as a useful construct.

In the case of the code I'm revieweing the `errors` is immediately checked after the sql command is executed and then an exception thrown with it as text.

This got me to wonder if I'm correctly seeing it that this negates the only advantage I could see of capturing the infomessage in the first place.

So my question here is: what are the advantages of capturing the info messages of SQL connections?

Or with other words, is the one advantage I saw the only one or am I *overlooking additional ones there?*

Comment: looks totally pointless to me. I want to know when there are exceptions, not an avalanche of info msgs! I never had to do this in the 20 years I've worked SQL Server

Comment: Same here mitch (although not 20 years only 16 in my case). But I want to make sure there is not something I'm overlooking there (and thus a reason my collegue put that code in other than 'rule of cool').

Comment: One possible advantage is collecting all errors in the set of command executes instead of throwing at the first error.

Comment: Note that by this mechanism you also get the output of `PRINT` and alike. Thus, it can be useful in the realm of applications that - sort of - do things like `SQLCMD` would do: run (user) scripts that output, well, informational messages, as they run.

Comment: For the close voters.... would be nice to know what reason (aka if the question is modifyable, or if its something intrinsic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not pointless.

As you mentioned, a SQL error with a severity level of 17 or above, will throw an exception, which **stops the execution of the SQL command**. Using a try catch block you can capture that exception.

But if the severity is less than 17, the **execution of command does not stop** and SQL is not throwing any exceptions. 
Using *InfoMessage*, you can capture those warnings and information messages from the SQL server.

Now the magic of your code is in this statement:

```
con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
```

If you want to **continue processing the rest of the statements in a command regardless of any errors produced by the server**, you set the *FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors* property of the *SqlConnection* to true. Doing this causes the connection to fire the InfoMessage event for errors instead of throwing an exception and interrupting processing.

For more information see the

> Handling Errors as InfoMessages

section in this MSDN article:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you mean that with a severity of less than 17 sql does not throw any exceptions? Or only when the info messages is set?

Comment: Severity of 16 or less will not stop the execution of command and will not throw exception, but it returns some information. You can think of the severity of 16 and less as warnings.

Comment: So without con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;  those are just "lost"?

Comment: No. It is the other way around. With that statement, if your SQL statement throw an exception, the execution will not stop.

Comment: Ah kk  wasn't sure with how it was formulated. tnx for the clarification

Comment: It appears that you also have to set FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors in order for update events to occur while statements runs (i.e. backup/restore stats). Otherwise, all the stats come through AFTER the statement runs. This causes a conundrum. I cannot get realtime percent complete without setting this, but if an error occurs during backup/restore, the SqlExecuteCommand( ) no longer throws an error. Instead I have to try and "manufacturer" the exception by hand.